# Is this type of question always too localized?

Tags: discussion, questions, too-localized

[css3 for this button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107042/css3-for-this-button)

Requesting help styling a button to a particular spec, no real assistance needed with *how* to do it, just which exact parameters he needs to punch in to make the button look right.

If I'm not mistaken, this is exactly what he's being paid to do with his time and so he shouldn't be offloading the required effort to SO..?

Comment: Okay so 15 minutes on SO and it was answered, versus maybe an hour or two of his time fiddling with values. I'm still not convinced we should do people's jobs for them though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about "always", and I don't know if that's something he's being hired to do but offloading to us, but that particular question seems like a good candidate for closure anyway so it's closed now.

Comment: Only reason I said the bit about hired to do it was due to this in the OP: `On a site I am working with ... I was asked to create a css that resembles to that image`